# Open chrome with cygwin

Tags: bash, google-chrome, cygwin

I am using a cygwin shell in windows 10. I am trying to figure out how to open chrome from the command line. I have tried typing chrome, google-chrome, chromium-browser, start chrome, open chrome, and many variations. I have even tried using my python shell, and I have also tried going to the folder where chrome.exe is located and opening it from there. The main reason I want to figure it out is because I plan to write HTML documents with python and then open them in chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `./chrome.exe` while being in the directory where the file is located? The path `./` is probably needed before the file name since the executable is not in a standard system path. You can of course also specify the full path to the file as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did work. I also did some more research and found out about the command 'cygstart' which works like the 'open' command, thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help please accept/upvote the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
cygstart "C:\path\to\chrome.exe"
```

or to open a specific URL,

```
cygstart "http://my/url.htm"
```